# How I can remove a ADUser with System.Management.Automation in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, active-directory, automation

I use System.Management.Automation for work with the powershell and c# and I want to use the Remove-ADUser command but I get a error: Here my Code.

```
public bool RemoveADUser(string sAMAccountName) { 

            Security key = new Security();

            try
            {
                ADPASSWORD = key.PasswordDecrypt("vnPYuGoPSvrSjDC+/5lUTQ==");
                //ADPASSWORD = "vnPYuGoPSvrSjDC+/5lUTQ==";

                SecureString SECUREADADMINPASSWORD = new SecureString();

                foreach (char x in sAMAccountName)
                {
                    SECUREADADMINPASSWORD.AppendChar(x);
                }

                SecureString pw = new SecureString();

                foreach (char x in ADPASSWORD)
                {
                    pw.AppendChar(x);
                }

                InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ADPS_LoadDefaultDrive", "0");
                initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "ActiveDirectory" });

                PSCredential crend = new PSCredential(ADNAME, pw);

                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial))
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    using (Pipeline p = runspace.CreatePipeline())
                    {
                        Command command = new Command("Remove-ADUser");
                        command.Parameters.Add("Identity", sAMAccountName);
                        command.Parameters.Add("Credential", crend);

                        p.Commands.Add(command);

                        p.Invoke();

                        return true;

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return false;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

the Code go to  p.Invoke(); but then I get this message:

in german:

Fehler in einem Befehl mit einer Eingabeaufforderung. Vom Hostprogramm oder Befehlstyp wird keine Benutzerinteraktion unterstützt. Für den Versuch, die Bestätigung anzufordern, wurde vom Host folgende Meldung verwendet: Möchten Sie diese Aktion wirklich ausführen?

in english:

Error in a command with a command prompt.The host program or command type isn't supported user interaction. For the experiment, to request confirmation, the following message from the host used was: Do you want to perform this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something with how you are calling this command is causing the command to prompt for more information but your C# engine "host" does not implement the required interface that allows the PowerShell engine to prompt the user for more info.  I see you pass in a password but the docs on this command do say:

> If you specify a user name for this parameter, the cmdlet prompts for
>   a password.

I wonder if something is borked with your PSCredential?